# Equivalence of two definitions of the $\hat{A}$-genus form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, characteristic-classes

Let $E$ be a real vector bundle and $\nabla$ a covariant derivative with curvature of $F$. On page 51 of [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628) it is claimed that "using the formula $\det A = \exp\operatorname{Tr}\ln A$" we obtain
$$\hat{A}(E,\nabla):=\mathrm{det}^{1/2}\bigg\{\frac{F/2}{\sinh F/2}\bigg\}=\exp\operatorname{Tr}\bigg\{\frac{1}{2}\ln\bigg\{\frac{F/2}{\sinh F/2}\bigg\}\bigg\}$$
but I am not quite happy with this explanation.

1. Obviously the formula $\det A = \exp\operatorname{Tr}\ln A$ doesn't even make sense for an arbitary matrix $A$ (i.e. a matrix with entries in some arbitrary commutative ring), so what is the exact theorem we are using here?
2. Even if I accept the formula $\det A = \exp\operatorname{Tr}\ln A$, I still dont get the desired formula without further assumptions, namely
   $$\mathrm{det}^{1/2}(A)=\det(A^{1/2})$$
   and
   $$\ln A^{1/2}=\frac{1}{2}\ln A.$$
   Similarly to above I am missing a rigorous justification, which would include stating the exact definition of the square roots.

I hope someone can fill the gaps or name a reference where all of this is discussed

Comment: It is important to notice that $\frac{F/2}{\sinh F/2}$ is a unipotent element in some matrix ring, and it is symmetric. You can read the formula as a comparison of two Taylor series in symmetric unipotent matrices around the unit matrix. It is sufficient to compare the two terms for symmetric matrices over $\mathbb R$ in a small neighboorhood of the unit matrix. I believe this is explained somewhere in the book you cited.

Comment: @SebastianGoette Thank you for the helpful comment. Why is symmetry important?

Comment: For symmetric matrices $A$ near the identity, the equality follows easily from the spectral theorem.